# AMD Graphics Card Unknown Display stuck at 640x480

Tags: 20.04, display, amd-graphics

Just installed a new AMD 5700XT card and the AMDGPU drivers, yet one of two displays are marked "Unknown Display" and forced into the 640x480 resolution.  I created a mode in xrandr that sets the display to 1920x1080, which results in the monitor saying "no signal".

Here is the output from running xrandr, the issue is with DisplayPort-2:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 connected 640x480+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       59.94* 
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04,
Any help would be wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me with a Radeon RX 6700 XT, also DisplayPort-2. I was using a displayport-to-hdmi cable, and once I switched to a straight-through hdmi cable the problem went away.